# Magento2.3.2 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException):

Tags: magento2, importexport, exception

Facing error while exporting customer main file

[image: error view]

Help to solve this issue...

Comment: I think one of your modules add extra filter type for customer attribute, but we cannot see witch one because you cut the error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got the error
Throwing error because of a custom customer attribute created by code.

I removed that attribute using InstallData.php script

```
<?php
 namespace Custom\Module\Setup;

  use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
  use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
  use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

 class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
  private $eavSetupFactory;

   public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) 
   {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
   }

   public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
   {
    $setup->startSetup();

    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_code_here');

    $setup->endSetup();
    }
 }
```

reason for posting answer here 
Hope it will help to someone who will face and facing same issues.

Happy Coding!!